# How to list of elements and use those elements as a header of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a list with some elements.
For example:
list= [name, phone_number,age,gender]
I want to use these elements as a header or column name in a pandas dataframe.

I would really appreciate your ideas.

Comment: you must provide more details, including a reproducible example and your own attempt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put all the values ​​that will be used as headers into an array using this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("yourtable.csv")
i = 0
headers = []
while i < len(data. index):
   headers.append(data.loc[i, "header of headers"])
   i = i + 1
```

You can create your table using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
```

**EDIT:**

With the new info just use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list)
```

Comment: Due to the lack of details, this is as far as I can help.

Comment: `for i in range(len(df. index))`. `headers = data.loc[:,"header of headers"]`. But I don't think this answers OP's question.